# $push into Array in Object in the document Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How do I $push into the Array which is in the Object in the document in mongoose?

The schema looks like this

```
{
  rating: {
      usersRated: Array,
      rating: Number
  }
}
```

I have tried `{rating: {$push: {usersRated: data.userId}}}`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [update the collection](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html).

In your case:

```
model.update({ _id: id }, { $push: { 'rating.usersRated': data.userId }}, callback);
```

On update, you should pass [the operator before the fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).